# capturing json data in typescript classes with functions

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive forms and having some trouble understanding how the data maps to the controls of the form. Let's take one example of an object control that has an id and a name. This control should be rendered as an input textbox and the user types in the Id. I am then using autocomplete functionality to remotely look up the object and populate the underlying object with data that looks like this

```
{ id: 1234, description: "Some description" }
```

Since, this is an object and not a string - the input box shows [object Object] as its value. I am assuming I need to provide a `toString` method for this object to be able to display a value like this `1234 - Some description`.

Here is the form configuration:

```
this.orderForm = this.fb.group({
  customer: '',
  ....
  items: this.fb.array([ this.initItems() ])
  ...
```

So `customer` is one of those objects and another similar object is on the `item` object.

```
export class Customer {
   id: string;
   descr: string;
   toString = () => this.id + " - " + this.descr
}

export class ItemDetail {
    id: string;
    descr: string;
    toString = () => this.id + " - " + this.descr
}

export class Order {
    id: string;
    ...
    customer: Customer;
    items: Item[]
}

export class Item {
    ...
    detail: ItemDetail
    ...
}
```

Once I have the order data, I am loading it in the form like this:

```
const itemsFGs = order.items.map(item => this.fb.group(item));
const itemsFA = this.fb.array(itemsFGs);
this.orderForm.setControl('items', itemsFA);
```

The problem is that the data is loaded as plain objects and is not type casted to the appropriate classes and because of that, there is no `toString` method on any of the nested objects which makes the input boxes show `[object Object]` instead of using the toString method.

Here is how the json for a sample order looks like:

```
{
  id: "1",
  customer: {
    id: "1",
    name: "some customer"
  },
  items: [{
     detail: {
       id: "1",
       descr: "some item"
     }
  }]
}
```

The main question is, how can I make sure that the data coming in as json is captured in proper classes so that methods like toString are available for proper display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key Note: When you are creating complex object types in typescript, always use interface.

```
export interface Customer {
   id: string;
   descr: string;
}
```

Also if you are not sure about the parameters coming from the service and you expect a undefined error, specify those properties as optional using the below code,

```
export interface ItemDetail {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    descr?: string; //optional
}

export interface Order {
    id: string;
    ...
    customer: Customer;
    items: Item[]
}
export interface Customer{
    id:string;
    name: string;
    address?: string; //optional
    dob?: Date;       //optional
```

}

By this you avoid the optional parameters getting binding to the actual object if they are not in the response. How ever they bind as expected when those properties are available in the service response.

Update 1 :

You should do another level of grouping

```
 this.form = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      customerGroup :this.fb.group({
               firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
               lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],   
      }, {validator: Validators.required})
      ....
  });
```

Comment: That sounds good and I'll try that out but in interface, you can't define methods and I want to specify the tostring method for these inner objects so they are displayed correctly in an input textbox. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: what toString() will do with  respect to textbox?

Comment: Lets say a customer object has this data `{id: 1, name: 'abc'}`. If I bind this object to an input text box using [formControl]="customer", the input box shows [object Object] as its value. I would like to show something like `1 - abc` instead

Comment: Your answer is helpful but no I'm still running into the same issues. What I understand from your answer is to create separate form controls for id and name fields under customer object but I want one text box for both and change the value of textbox to show both values and bind the form control tip customer object. I feel like it's such a simple and common use case and I can't seem to find a single example for it. With the current setup, the text box shows [object] as value of textbox unless i explicitly define a tostring method on the json object which suggests that tostring method is...

Comment: ... Being used to display the value in textbox. That's why i wanted to use a class where i can define a tostring method  r and then cast the json to this class but apparently that's not possible either and interfaces can't have methods.